# Using gnu-iostream.h header

Tags: c++, gnuplot, gnuplot-iostream

I am trying to plot directly in my C program to Gnuplot, so I am using the header

```
#include "gnuplot-iostream.h"
```

But it is missing a dependency of file_descriptor.hpp. I've already copied the entire directory of Gnuplot into my current directory. Does anyone have an idea what a fix could be? I have tried searching on spotlight for the file but I can't find it (I think spotlight is just sketchy).

Comment: *I've already copied the entire directory of Gnuplot into my current directory.* not a good plan. Instead pass the location of the gnuplot include folder to the compiler. With GCC and GCC-like compilers you do that by adding `-I<path to gnuplot include folder>` to the compiler command line.

Comment: file_descriptor.hpp is the name of a a boost header.  Perhaps you also need to install boost. If you're using Linux computer you should be able to get a pre-assembled boost library that matches the default compiler version from the package manager. If you have already installed boost, same as above: `-I<path to boost include folder>`

Comment: I have the same issue and I saw that all people link with -lboost_system, .... etc. But I use CMAKE Lists and I do not get how I link correctly to boost etc.